# In Java, what is Class class=(Class)object and how should it be used?

Tags: java, selenium, oop

```
Object x = itr.getInstance();
AbstractGuiTest currentCase = (AbstractGuiTest)x;
WebDriver driver  = currentCase.getDriver();
```

AbstractGuiTest is a class.

Can someone explain how the syntax of having the class within brackets beside an object like so work?

Need to know some more examples where a class can be used in that manner.

**Update:**

itr is of the type ITestResult

Comment: It’s a cast. Is `itr` a `Class` instance?  If so, you don’t need to cast if the class object is typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is to cast object x of type `Object` which is superclass of all the classes in java to `AbstractGuiTest`

This happens quite frequently in Java because of inheritance. 
So, in your case `AbstractGuiTest`is subclass of `Object` class or in other words inherits from `Object`. So, by using this `AbstractGuiTest currentCase = (AbstractGuiTest)x;` you are making `x` of type `AbstractGuiTest`.

If you use this typecasting on classes which are not in the same class hierarchy, you will get `ClassCastException`

Another example could be:
Animal is superClass and Dog is its subclass

`public class Animal{
   //some code goes in here
}`

`public class Dog extends Animal{
//some code goes in here
}`

Now, you can use this syntax:

`Animal a = new Dog();
Dog d = (Dog) a;`

You should read more on inheritance in java to make this concept clear.

Comment: This cleared it up for me. I am reading this for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: @SteroidKing666 Glad that it cleared it up for you. If it helped,  please accept the answer :)

Comment: Done. Sorry I have only recently started using SO to ask questions or comments so didn't know about accepting.

Comment: @SteroidKing666 thanks, it starts from humble beginnings.